# A question on the proof environment of amsthm

Tags: amsthm

I would like to alternate between two proof environments under the `amsthm` package, e.g. distinguished between `\begin{proof1} ... \end{proof1}` and `\begin{proof2} ... \end{proof2}`. In these I want to use different end signs like QED or `$\blacksquare$`.

How may I do this?

Comment: You've been here some time already:  Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  In particular: The term and concept of MWE  should be known ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer My question is perfectly intelligible without a MWE, and so much so that it already got a perfectly acceptable answer. Some times a MWE may just obfuscate matters.

Comment: I think it's better for non-high-rep users to understand your question, to provide a MWE, but it's your choice, of course.

Comment: OK I will attempt to remember that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define a `proofi` environment based on `proof` but making the desired redefinition for the `\qedsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newenvironment{proof1}[1][\proofname]
  {\begin{proof}[#1]\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}}
  {\end{proof}}
\newenvironment{proof2}[1][\proofname]
  {\begin{proof}[#1]\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\textsc{qed}}}
  {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Test text.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof1}
Test text.
\end{proof1}

\begin{proof2}
Test text.
\end{proof2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `xparse`, you can easily set another optional argument allowing to specify the symbol, if desired; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{proofi}{d()O{\proofname}}
  {\begin{proof}[#2]\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{#1}}}
  {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proofi}
Test text.
\end{proofi}

\begin{proofi}($\blacksquare$)
Test text.
\end{proofi}

\begin{proofi}(\textsc{qed})
Test text.
\end{proofi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, redefining `proof`:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}

\LetLtxMacro\oldproof\proof
\let\oldendproof\endproof

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{proof}{d()O{\proofname}}
  {\oldproof[#2]\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{#1}}}
  {\oldendproof}
```